# Trouble Using the less command

Tags: command-line, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, putty, less

When I use the `less` command in order to view a textfile in a directory, it keeps on returning that the file is a directory.
Also tried using the `cat` command and also get the same result every time.
However, when I use the list command it gives me the the content of the directory without the text file.

Where am I getting it wrong?

[image]

Comment: If `less` say's that it is a directory, it probably is. Try listing your working directory with `ls -l` instead of just `ls` (even though the colors of the ls indicates it is a directory). Or use `file  somefile` ... like `file my_school`.

Comment: By the way, you are using root user, which isn't enabled by default in Ubuntu. What version of Ubuntu are you using, and why are you using root user ?

Comment: As a self-described newbie, running as root will eventually result in disaster: you will inevitably delete some crucial file or directory, and I bet you don't have a backup.

Comment: When you run `ls my_school`, you can clearly see that `my_school` is a directory - containing (among other items) an entry `my_school`. Likely it is *that* that is the file i.e. from where you are now, either `less my_school/my_school` or `cd my_school ; less my_school`